# How can I summarize nodes using calculation data from other nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath

Using XSLT 1.0, how can I summarize subnodes under a given node while modifiyng the content with data from another set of nodes in an elegant way? Assume I have this xml:

```
<Root>
    <ExchangeRates>
        <ExchangeRate>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Rate>6.4</Rate>
        </ExchangeRate>
        <ExchangeRate>
            <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
            <Rate>8.44</Rate>
        </ExchangeRate>
        <ExchangeRate>
            <CurrencyCode>SEK</CurrencyCode>
            <Rate>1</Rate>
        </ExchangeRate>
    </ExchangeRates>
    <Prices>
        <Price>
            <Currency>SEK</Currency>
            <Amount>10000</Amount>
        </Price>
        <Price>
            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
            <Amount>1000</Amount>
        </Price>
        <Price>
            <Currency>USD</Currency>
            <Amount>1000</Amount>
        </Price>
    </Prices>
</Root>
```

I want the sum of all Amounts converted into SEK with the help of the ExchangeRates. The result should be:

```
<SumInSEK>24840</SumInSEK>
```

If I didn't have to convert the amounts I would simply use the xpath sum() function. Is is possible to use that function in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible solution without recursive calls but with exsl extension.
This make use of the key definition form @softwarebear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
        extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:key name="rates" match="//ExchangeRate/Rate" use="parent::*/child::CurrencyCode/text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Prices"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Prices">
        <SUmInSEK>
            <xsl:variable name="price_SEK">
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="SEK" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($price_SEK)//price_SEK)"/>
        </SUmInSEK>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Price" mode="SEK">
        <price_SEK>
            <xsl:value-of
            select="number(Amount) * number( key('rates', Currency) )" />
        </price_SEK>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Wiht the output

```
<SUmInSEK>24840</SUmInSEK>
```

Comment: Nice, I chose to use this solution. Learned a bit from it as well. Two things I am curious about: Why do you use the mode attribute in the Price template and not a match pattern? Why do you have two slashes before the price_SEK node name?

Comment: The small example would also work without mode. But if you have to do something else with the Price tag than you can still add another Price  template (without mode). Your are right the a single slash would do. (Seems I was a lite careless)

Answer (score 2):

I thought this might be simple ... but I don't think you can use sum() on this occasion ... the best I can do is a recursive template.

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" 
>
  <xsl:key name="rates" match="//ExchangeRate/Rate" use="parent::*/child::CurrencyCode/text()"/>

  <xsl:template match="//Prices">
    <SUmInSEK>
      <xsl:call-template name="sum"/>
    </SUmInSEK>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="sum">
    <xsl:param name="iterator" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="total" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="price" select="child::Price[$iterator]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="current">
      <xsl:value-of select="number($price/child::Amount) * number( key('rates', $price/child::Currency) )"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="newtotal">
      <xsl:value-of select="$total + $current"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$price/following-sibling::Price">
        <xsl:call-template name="sum">
          <xsl:with-param name="iterator" select="$iterator+1"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$newtotal"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$total + $current"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="* | /">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text() | @*">
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction() | comment()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Better than my recursive try. +1 Buy why using the iterator and the Price node as parameter?

Comment: Was just the first solution I got working, I'm guessing I can work my way along the price nodes as the current context instead ... oh just read your answer ... I didn't know we could do that 8-)